# Add custom row as 1st row in grid extjs

Tags: extjs

I want to add custom row as 1st row in grid.Supose in this link

http://ngs.woc.noaa.gov/storms/scripts/ext-3.2.1/examples/grid/row-editor.html

I want to insert custom hardcorded value as first row in this grid .How to do this i dont want to do it with store.Bascially i want to add div after header and populate my string into that

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[`grid.getStore().insert( index, records )`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-insert) will do this if you set `index = 0`

Comment: It is right answer why this guy downvote does make sense

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code:

```
var grid = Ext.getCmp("yourGridId").getStore()
var myArray=new Array()
myArray['id'] = '1';
myArray['value'] = 'Dummy';
var rec = new Ext.data.Record(myArray);
grid.insert(0, rec);
```